# What happens when one of the item in Bundle is rejected at some aproval step

Tags: 2013, workflow

My question is specific to Bundle workflow.

Suppose i have a Bundle B having Workflow W attached to it.I have 3 components and 2 pages in Bundle B.My workflow has 7 step approval process through various teams.Suppose i have manually triggered the Workflow of Bundle.

What happens when one of my item in this Bundle B is rejected by one of my Approver.

Question:

1. My complete Bundle with all items will come back to first step of Workflow.
2. Only the item sent back will come back to first step of workflow.
3. In  the External Activity class i am getting 6 subject ID's - 1 for Bundle, 3 for component, 2 for pages. I understand that 3 component and 2 pages ID's will be there.
   What do i need to do with Bundle object ID in first activity. Do i need to pass this object through workflow steps as well.
4. When all my items inside the workflow has finished its all activity my Bundle will dissolve automatically other i can see the bundle in Tridion.
5. If one of the item in Bundle has finished all Approval Step.Will it disappear from Bundle B.Once all items disappear this Bundle will disappear at last.

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking if 1 *or* 2 is true as well as if 4 *or* 5 is true?

Answer (score 4):

Since a bundle workflow is a single workflow process, you cannot reject items individually - you reject or approve *all* of the items in the bundle.

So, if one of your assets is not ready, the bundle is not ready and everything goes back to whatever step you defined as the next one after reject decision.

This should answer questions 1, 2 and 5.

What happens to a bundle after the workflow process is finished is decided in your Workflow Definition - Bundles will remain in the system or be removed based on the preference you set in there.

On Question #3, you get the bundle object so that you can access any bundle properties you would need, like Bundle Metadata for instance (I know of one implementation where the "go live" date is specified in the Bundle Metadata and this is used to schedule publishing).

Answer (score 2):

The entire Bundle goes through Workflow but it doesn't have to go back to the first step. It depends on your manual or automatic activities and decisions. With the Legacy Pack you can do separate individual item Workflow, though this might conflict with your plans for Bundles (since having items checked out means you could only run one or the other type of workflow).

You can use the Bundle to get and reference the other items for publishing for example. Not sure if you need to pass the reference along in code, though.

The items in the Bundle will change if configured and users or code changes the list. The whole Bundle dissolves at the end, but this is optional based on the Bundle Schema's Workflow settings.

I haven't seen items individually "dissolve" or remove themselves in a Bundle, but this might be something you could implement. You might also look into including other Bundles in your main workflow Bundle if you want them to dissolve independently.

Comment: Alvin -I think i confused you,Lemme rephrase the my main question .If my Bundle has 5 items in it. These 5 items are used in different pages in Tridion. Suppose i manually trigger Bundle workflow on this bundle. What happens when one of my component changes are not approved by one of my Approver. Does the complete bundle will come back to first step or only that component only will come back to first step(Create/Edit) .  Because my content author will not like if complete bundle is coming back to Create/Edit .

Comment: Okay I see what you're asking now. Nuno's response and my first line should answer that: the *entire* Bundle goes through workflow (and is rejected together). For reasonably-sized Bundles authors will manage--it's their content and/or pages after all. One of the points of Bundle workflow is reviewing sets of items in context so an update to a single item probably means you should at least *review* related items. Instead of going back to Create/Edit, why not have a "Minor Change" or "Review Edit" step instead?